# Passing JSON data with request using $http.get() or $http.post()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call a webservice that requires me to pass a JSON object to it. Though I'm not sure whether I'm doing it right. My service does the following:

```
this.updateAddressDetails = function (address, personId) {

    var url = 'http://213.456.123.456:8080/Address?' +
    'action=updateAddress' +
    '&personId=' + personId +
    '&address=' + JSON.stringify(address);

    return $http.get(url);

  }
```

But I get the following error server side (I'm using Java Servlets):

> Error parsing HTTP request header

Which leads me to assume that I'm not passing the JSON to the server the correct way. Any tips?

Comment: Does your requestServlet support JSON format? You use Spring MVC or other framework on the server side?

Comment: Just normal vanilla servlets. I'm trying to get the JSON in the request by going 'request.getParameter("address")' and then serializing it to a Java POJO (Addres) by using Gson.

Comment: verify the request header in your browser, maybe there are some special caracter like '&' in your address?

Comment: why not post this rather than put it in a get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this if your are working with angular JS:

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {

// Simple POST request example (passing data) :
$http.post("/createProject/"+ id +"", {
    projectTitle: pTitle,
    userID      : id
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available

    console.log("project created");
    console.log("this is the response data " + data);
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
};
```